# Could not find directory

Tags: cordova

Did I install wrong or anything else wrong?hope someone help me, thanks.
[image]

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little more?

Comment: I just het the same error. [Here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-9687) is the issue and it seems resolved, but maybe newer versions of software have it again. [Here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-9783?focusedCommentId=14965270&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-14965270) they say that it will be fixed soon.

Comment: See [https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-9687](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-9687). The last comment says that it's fixed in newer versions.